# Different ways of summing an array by continuously dividing by 2

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of n integers, there are n! ways to permute them. For each permutation
We can compute a sum a1+a2/2+a3/4+a4/8+...
The nth integer is divided by 2^(n-1) in the sum. we are also given an integer q and have
to find the number of permutations that will result in the sum >=q

**My Thoughts:**
There is a simple brute force approach, but that will be very inefficient.
I am not sure how this could be optimized
The brute force could be generate all the permutations and calculate
sum for each of them and see how many exceed q

Comment: You should describe your simple brute-force approach.

Comment: @user3386109 added explanation for brute force approach

Comment: Ok, so the first level of optimization is to note that if `a1 >= q` then you don't need to go any further. For example, given an array of 10 elements, there are 10! possible permutations. But for each element that's `>= q`, there are 9! permutations that don't need to be checked, because all of them will have a sum `>= q`.

Comment: Can any of the *integers* be smaller than zero?

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @user3386109's comment, I'd suggest a recursive solution, so that we can discard as soon as possible every `a1 >= q`, but also every `(a1 + a2/2) >= q`, and so on.

This will still be slow, but saves around 40% of time for an array of 8 elements and around 60% for 10 elements when compared with a brute force approach. I'm not a Java programmer, so here are the Python implementations of the two approaches (I tried to keep them not too "Pythonic" so they can hopefully be understood by a non-Python programmer):

```py
#brute force
from itertools import permutations

def sum_by_perm(ls, q):
    good = 0
    n_range = len(ls)
    for p in permutations(ls):
        x = sum(map(lambda x,y:x/2**y, p, range(n_range)))
        if x < q:
            good+=1
    return good

> sum_by_perm([19,3,8,5,9,2,11,7,4,33],25) #this takes about 17 secs on my PC
2748657

#recursion
def sum_by_recurs(ls, q, lvl=0, current=0):
    if len(ls) == 0:
        return 1
    divi = 2**lvl
    good = 0
    for i,n in enumerate(ls):
        check = n/divi+current
        if check >= q:
            continue
        good += sum_by_recurs(ls[:i]+ls[i+1:], q, lvl+1, check)
    else:
        return good

> sum_by_recurs([19,3,8,5,9,2,11,7,4,33],25) #this takes about 6.5 secs on my PC
2748657
```